# value of lommel function for negative first parameter and positive second parameter

Tags: calculus, functions, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

I need to know an equivalent expression for lommel function with these parameters as follow :
S(-ν-1,ν) (z) for ν > 0 and all z and v can be integer or not.

I read the book (p.348-349) "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions"  following link :
https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions/page/n357/mode/2up?q=%C2%A710.73

But I noticed that if I want use the relation ['10.73 (1)' in above book] then p = v so the term of 1/(v-p)m+1 ("pochhamer function") in summation goes to infinity. So what can I do? Also I'm interested in this case that what would be the limit on lommel when v >> 1
I woud appreciat it if someone can help.
thanks.

Comment: surprisingly I can't find lommel function in wolfram mathematica wolhttp://demonstrations.wolfram.com/The...

Comment: dlmf site refers to a good reference:
W. Babister (1967) Transcendental Functions Satisfying Nonhomogeneous Linear Differential Equations. The Macmillan Co., New York.  
but unfortunately it's not accessible free . At least if someone has it or knows where I can find it I will appreciate